# Como trabalhar com objeto como atributo no cadastro de outro objeto usando JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

tenho uma classe Agendamento. Nessa classe tenho um objeto de Tarefa. Minha duvida é, ao criar a tela para registrar o agendamento, terei um campo para registrar a Tarefa desse agendamento. Imaginando que essas tarefas já estão cadastradas na base de dados. Qual a melhor forma de trabalhar isso na view, para que o usuario possa selecionar a tarefa e alimentar o atributo Tarefa do Agendamento para realizar o cadastro?
Pesquisei coisas como "Objeto de outra classe como atributo na JSP", mas não encontrei muita coisa, desculpem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo,
O processo é bem simples.
Primeiro, você vai fazer uma chamada pro banco para exibir todas as tarefas disponíveis. Você pode salvar essas tarefas num select, por exemplo, onde o `value` é o `id` da mesma.
Se você for usar requisições `ajax`, poderia ser algo como:

```
var tarefas;
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  sucess: function(data){
    /* Vamos imaginar que seu retorno seja um json contendo todas
    as tarefas */
    tarefas = data.tarefas; //aqui temos acesso a todos objetos tarefas
  }
});
var select_tarefas = $("<select></select>");
$(tarefas).each(function(i,e){
  var op = $("<option></option>");
  op.val(e.id).text(e.nome);
  select_tarefas.append(op);
});
```

No final você terá uma estrutura html mais ou menos assim:

```
<select>
  <option value="4332">Tarefa 1</option>
  <option value="4354">Tarefa 2</option>
  <option value="4123">Tarefa 3</option>
</select>
```

Isso é apenas 1 das diversas formas de ter todos os dados da tarefa na sua **view**. (Você escolhe uma maneira que for mais conveniente pra você)

Agora, você precisar dar um `name` para o elemento para poder ter acesso a ele no *backend*.

Na linha

```
var select_tarefas = $("<select></select>");
```

Você pode fazer:

```
var select_tarefas = $("<select name='q_tarefas'></select>");
```

Ou até mesmo:

```
var select_tarefas = $("<select></select>");
select_tarefas.attr("name", "q_tarefas");
```

Tendo essa estrutura correta, ao dar um *submit* pra um *link* onde está mapeado uma *servlet* ou até mesmo uma *JSP*, você poderá ter acesso a tarefa através da linha:

```
request.getParameter("q_tarefa"); //Vai retornar o ID selecionado la no front.
```

Dai basta você montar manualmente um objeto de tarefa, e *setar* no seu objeto de Agendamento, exemplo:

```
Agendamento a = new Agendamento();
Tarefa t = new Tarefa();

t.setId(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("q_tarefa"));

a.setTarefa(t);
```

Prontinho, agora você tem no *backend* um objeto de agendamento que tem como atributo um objeto de tarefa.
Embora seja um objeto só com o *ID*, é apenas o que você precisa se estiver usando banco de dados relacional.
Muito provavelmente sua tabela de agendamento tem uma *foreign key* que é o ID da tabela tarefa.

Espero ter ajudado a esclarecer um pouco as coisas.
Qualquer dúvida, só comentar na resposta.

Abraços.

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Deu certo.